# WebServices Calculator Example using Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have created an sample application of calculator for sum of two numbers using webservices in Java by using Jersey service.

My code is : 
Calculator.java

```
package p1;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@WebService
@Path("/CalculatorService")
public class Calculator
{
    @WebMethod
    public String sum(int x,int y)
    {
        return ""+(x+y);
    }
}
```

Calculator.java:

```
package mypack;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAXWS SI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.0_02-b08-fcs
 * Generated source version: 2.0
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "Calculator", targetNamespace = "http://p1/")
public interface Calculator {


    /**
     * 
     * @param arg1
     * @param arg0
     * @return
     *     returns java.lang.String
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "sum", targetNamespace = "http://p1/", className = "mypack.Sum")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "sumResponse", targetNamespace = "http://p1/", className = "mypack.SumResponse")
    public String sum(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        int arg0,
        @WebParam(name = "arg1", targetNamespace = "")
        int arg1);

}
```

CalculatorService.java:

```
package mypack;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAXWS SI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.0_02-b08-fcs
 * Generated source version: 2.0
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "CalculatorService", targetNamespace = "http://p1/", wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8081/MyCalculatorWs/CalculatorService?WSDL")
public class CalculatorService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL CALCULATORSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8081/MyCalculatorWs/CalculatorService?WSDL");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CALCULATORSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public CalculatorService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public CalculatorService() {
        super(CALCULATORSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://p1/", "CalculatorService"));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns Calculator
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "CalculatorPort")
    public Calculator getCalculatorPort() {
        return (Calculator)super.getPort(new QName("http://p1/", "CalculatorPort"), Calculator.class);
    }

}
```

ObjectFactory.java:

```
package mypack;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the mypack package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Sum_QNAME = new QName("http://p1/", "sum");
    private final static QName _SumResponse_QNAME = new QName("http://p1/", "sumResponse");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: mypack
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Sum }
     * 
     */
    public Sum createSum() {
        return new Sum();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link SumResponse }
     * 
     */
    public SumResponse createSumResponse() {
        return new SumResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Sum }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://p1/", name = "sum")
    public JAXBElement<Sum> createSum(Sum value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Sum>(_Sum_QNAME, Sum.class, null, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link SumResponse }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://p1/", name = "sumResponse")
    public JAXBElement<SumResponse> createSumResponse(SumResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<SumResponse>(_SumResponse_QNAME, SumResponse.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

package-info.java:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://p1/")
package mypack;
```

Sum.java:

```
package mypack;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for sum complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="sum">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="arg0" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
 *         &lt;element name="arg1" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sum", propOrder = {
    "arg0",
    "arg1"
})
public class Sum {

    protected int arg0;
    protected int arg1;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the arg0 property.
     * 
     */
    public int getArg0() {
        return arg0;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the arg0 property.
     * 
     */
    public void setArg0(int value) {
        this.arg0 = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the arg1 property.
     * 
     */
    public int getArg1() {
        return arg1;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the arg1 property.
     * 
     */
    public void setArg1(int value) {
        this.arg1 = value;
    }

}
```

SumResponse.java:

```
package mypack;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for sumResponse complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="sumResponse">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="return" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sumResponse", propOrder = {
    "_return"
})
public class SumResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    protected String _return;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the return property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getReturn() {
        return _return;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the return property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setReturn(String value) {
        this._return = value;
    }

}
```

And my web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CalculatorEx</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.restful.demo.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am executing my application using:
`http://localhost:8080/CalculatorEx/rest/CalculatorService`

i am getting the error like this:

```
exception:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

root cause:
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: is it because your web.xml is referring to "com.restful.demo.resources" but your code is in the package "mypack"?

Comment: I am getting the same error after adding the package"mypack" in web.xml

Comment: I am working from this example:
http://www.jgeppert.com/2009/03/restful-web-services-jax-rs-mit-jersey/
Please give suggestions how do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>com.restful.demo.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Change it to:

```
 <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>p1</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: I am getting error after adding the package in web.xml:
The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Method Not Allowed).

Comment: @Praveensai How you are calling web-service? How you are passing parameters for sum?

Comment: For that we are using xml and by using the annotations:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
For passing parameter for sum:
@XmlType(name = "sum", propOrder = {
    "arg0",
    "arg1"}) in the sum class

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sumResponse", propOrder = {
    "_return" in SumResponse class

Comment: Please add @GET/@POST before public String sum(int x,int y) to specify which type of request you want for web-method. And call it accordingly using GET/POST. This will solve above error. All the best.

Comment: After adding the @POST to the method it is giving the same error

Comment: Are you calling web-method by using URL? You need to call it from HTML form and setting method as POST in form /any other method using POST like using apache lib for POST request. Or If are calling method by using URL set it to @GET.

Comment: I have not created any method using URL and also HTML form, it will take the index.jsp as the default as welcome page and it will use it.

Comment: But how index.jsp is calling web-service?

Comment: I have added @GET to the method public String sum(int x,int y) it is showing  
Unsupported Media Type:
description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type).
Then i added @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML) to the method
then also it is showing the error above

Comment: I am working from this example:
http://www.jgeppert.com/2009/03/restful-web-services-jax-rs-mit-jersey/
Please give suggestions how do it.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is a code using a JAX-WS web service and a web.xml registering Jersey servlet. There is not a single JAX-RS resource in your code. So that's why you are getting the error. Look at the JAX-RS spec and see how to write JAX-RS resources.

Comment: I am working from this example:
http://www.jgeppert.com/2009/03/restful-web-services-jax-rs-mit-jersey/
Please give suggestions how do it.

Comment: That sample looks fine, but your code is very different. Seems like you replaced all the jax-rs annotations with jax-ws ones. So no wonder it doesn't work. Just read any introductory article on jax-rs. E.g. http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html

Comment: The example is working fine but not giving all the values in the xml

Comment: What do you mean by "not giving all values"? Either the result is XML, or not. It can't be in-between. Also have a look at [documentiation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/xml.html#d4e820).